# How do you access a function of a wrapped template object

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a wrapper over an existing class. What is the best way to write a wrapper without changing any client code that used the existing class directly?

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
// ...other wrapper data/functionality...
private:
    T myObject;
};

main()
{
    Wrapper<A> wrappedA;
    wrappedA.foo();
}
```

***Compilation fails in msvc with error C2039: 'foo' : is not a member of 'Wrapper'***

What is the best way to make the template wrapper class work without changing any code in main?

- The selection operator. cannot be overloaded
- Writing a cast operator to type T doesn't help as the compiler will not attempt to cast before doing the selection
- We can write a get function that will return the inner myObject member but the client code in main has to be rewritten. This is not good if there is plenty of existing code that uses myObject directly without the new wrapper class we are trying to write.

**Edit**

- I would like to write a wrapper class over myObject without having to change any existing client code which used myObject directly
- A::foo() cannot be brought up into the wrapper as other types T may not have T::foo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call it via the `A` instance:

```
wrappedA.myObject.foo();
```

Your wrapper isn't a very clever wrapper, so you need to know that it holds an instance called `myObject`. You can make it clever by giving it a conversion operator:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    T myObject;

    operator const T& () const { return myObject; }
    operator T& () { return myObject; }
};
```

This will allow you to use it in places where an `A` is required:

```
void bar(const A& a) { a.foo(); } // (make A::foo() a const method)

Wrapper<A> a;
bar(a);  // OK
```

Comment: The problem is, all types that are in the wrapper need to have a non member function that will cause the cast to be called.

Answer (score 2):

Provide operator-> returning pointer to the wrapped class if having to use -> to access methods is not an issue:

```
template
class Wrapper
{
public:
  T* operator->() { return &myObject; }
  T const* operator->() const { return &myObject; }
...
};
```

But if you really want dot to be used to access methods, then maybe derive Wrapper from T?
(but then your class is not much of a Wrapper at all :D)

Comment: That's one way since -> can be overloaded. This needs all calls to the existing myObject to be changed from . to -> though

Answer (score 2):

use `wrappedA.myObject.foo();` instead of `wrappedA.foo();`

Comment: The problem here is that the client code still has to be modified and there could be plenty of existing client code to modify. I would like to write a transparent wrapper over the existing myObject without having to change the API of any client code.